# Shopware 6 with APP_ENV=dev does not display the debug toolbar

Tags: shopware6

After reading this https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-scripts#developing-debugging-scripts, I updated the .env file and set "dev" as APP_ENV value but the debug bar is not displayed anywhere in the storefront.

Is there something else to do?

My local Shopware version is 6.4.18.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you used the Symfony Flex template via `composer create-project shopware/production` you have to additionally install `shopware/dev-tools`

```
composer require shopware/dev-tools
```

Comment: I had the same issue when installing 6.5 using the shopware-installer.phar.php file. Running the composer command solved it.